# Is syscall(2) part of a standard?

Tags: linux, posix, system-calls

syscall(2) does not seem to be part of POSIX or C standard library. Is it part of any standard?

Are all libc implementations implementing syscall(2)? If it is not part of any standard such as POSIX, is it just a convention that all libc implementations provided syscall(2)?

Comment: Even on Linux, `syscall` is quite unportable between platorms. E.g. some architectures multiplex through `socketcall`, some don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) online yields no results for **syscall**.

Grepping the offline versions doesn't either.

POSIX doesn't really concerns itself with syscalls vs. pure userspace functions. (It mentions it in the intro that it's only concerned about semantics of the standardized functions, and it doesn't care about whether those functions wrap system calls or not.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, because the notion of [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) is quite specific.

<sup>(I guess -but don't really know- that the optional "POSIX" interface inside Windows might not have `syscall(2)`)</sup>

However, past Unix implementations from the 1980s had some `syscall(2)` thing.